# Check if two dates are consecutive using java streams

Tags: java, date, java-8, java-stream

How to check if a list has consecutive dates.Suppose I have list like below

```
List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>();
dates.add(java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.of(2016, 11, 12)));
dates.add(java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.of(2016, 12, 15)));
dates.add(java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.of(2016, 11, 13)));
```

I tried holding the previous date in temp varilable but that didnt work

Comment: So you want to sort the list by date ?

Comment: Why do you want to use streams?

Comment: "I tried holding the previous date in temp varilable but that didnt work" please show what you tried.

Comment: Would it be possible to work on the `LocalDate` instances before converting them to `java.sql.Date`? Would seem more natural to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really just want to know if your list contains any consecutive dates and you really want to use streams, this might be a solution:

```
List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>();
dates.add(java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.of(2016, 11, 12)));
dates.add(java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.of(2016, 12, 15)));
dates.add(java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.of(2016, 11, 13)));

boolean hasConsecutiveDates
    = dates.stream()
           .sorted()
           .anyMatch(new Predicate<java.sql.Date>() {
             private java.sql.Date previous;

             @Override
             public boolean test(java.sql.Date date) {
               boolean consecutiveByDay = false;
               if (previous != null) {
                 consecutiveByDay =
                     ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(previous.toLocalDate(), date.toLocalDate()) == 1;
               }

               previous = date;
               return consecutiveByDay;
             }
           });
```

Please be aware that streams are actually **not made to keep a state and know about the other elements** in the stream. Thats why we need the shown predicate to keep track of the previous element.

Comment: I felt sure it would be possible with streams, and just as sure I didn’t want to bother. You did. Bravo.

Comment: What about the ability of parallelization?

Comment: Instead of mapping to a `Boolean`, to append `.anyMatch(e -> e)`, you can use `anyMatch` in the first place, implementing a `Predicate<Date>` instead of a `Function<Date, Boolean>`. In either case, stateful functions are strongly discouraged in Streams. The only clean solution would be a Collector.

Comment: @MenoHochschild using the approach I suggested you can't parallelize, because it relies on the sorted processing of the stream.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a clean approach which also enables you to use a parallel `Stream`.

```
List<Date> dates = new ArrayList<>();
dates.add(java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.of(2016, 11, 12)));
dates.add(java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.of(2016, 12, 15)));
dates.add(java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.of(2016, 11, 13)));
dates.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
boolean hasConsecutiveDates = IntStream.range(1, dates.size())
    .anyMatch(i -> 
         ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(dates.get(i - 1).toLocalDate(), dates.get(i).toLocalDate()) == 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Streams are great for many purposes, but I’m not sure this is one. Here’s my go (without streams):

```
    Collections.sort(dates);
    for (int ix = 0; ix < dates.size() - 1; ix++) {
        Date d1 = dates.get(ix);
        Date d2 = dates.get(ix + 1);
        if (d1.toLocalDate().plusDays(1).equals(d2.toLocalDate())) {
            System.out.println("Consecutive: " + d1 + " and " + d2);
        }
    }
```

It prints:

```
Consecutive: 2016-11-12 and 2016-11-13
```

Answer (score -1):

why don't you use `before()` and `after()` functions inherited from `java.util.date`
you can use sorting algorithm of your choice but comparing logic can be like

```
boolean isConsecutive = false; 
if(dates.get(1).before(dates.get(2)) || dates.get(1).after(dates.get(2))){
     isConsecutive = true;
}
```

Comment: I wanted it by using streams java 8

Comment: `before()` will tell you that November 1 is before December 25, not whether they are consecutive. Similar for `after()`, only the other way around.